# Replace **NULL** values in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I'm pulling my hair out here. I need to replace **null** values in a pandas dataframe column. These are specifically null values not NaN values.

I've tried:

```
trainData['Embarked'].replace(trainData['Embarked'].isnull, embarkedMost, regex=True)

trainData['Embarked'].replace('', embarkedMost, regex=True)

trainData['Embarked'].replace('', embarkedMost, regex=True, inplace=True)

trainData['Embarked'].str.replace('', embarkedMost, regex=True)

trainData['Embarked'].isnull().replace(np.nan, embarkedMost, regex=True)

trainData['Embarked'].fillna(embarkedMost)

trainData['Embarked'].str.replace(np.Nan, embarkedMost, regex=True)

trainData['Embarked'].str.replace(pd.isnull, embarkedMost, regex=True)

trainData['Embarked'].replace(r'^\s+$', embarkedMost, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Then:

```
trainData.to_csv(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'full.csv'), sep=',')
```

Whereafter I load the dataset into excel to check but none of these change the dataset though.

This provides me with the correct indices for empty values:

```
print(np.where(pd.isnull(trainData['Embarked'])))
```

I wanted to use apply with lambda but read that it is horribly inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind everyone

Solved with:

```
trainData['Embarked'] = trainData['Embarked'].fillna(embarkedMost)
```

I think I may have opened a csv in a different directory